# How to embed single photo from Google photos album

Tags: google-photos, embed

How do I embed a single photo from my Google photo album to a website now that Picasa embed has been disabled?

Comment: I see on the Google Photos Product forum a bunch of complaints from people who are missing this feature ([example](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/V4aKmE9ib10)) with advice to use the "Feedback" tool to let Google know this is a feature you're missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the direct link to an image in my Google Photos?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92777/how-to-get-the-direct-link-to-an-image-in-my-google-photos)

Answer (score 7):

It's not as straightforward as one would like, but you can do it this way:

1. Find the photo in Google Photos you want to include
2. Open the "Share" menu and click "Get link"
3. Either click the link that is created or click "Copy" and paste that address into a new browser window
4. That'll bring you to a new shared album with just that photo in it; you need to get the filename of the image
5. Click the image so that it's zoomed in
6. Right-click the image and choose "Copy image address" (or whatever your browser's equivalent is)

You now have the URL for the "public" image that you can use on your page. You'd probably use it in an image tag similar to:

```
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/NWfbsppj..." />
```

The URL for the image is incredibly long, but should work just fine, like this one I picked somewhat at random:

[image: beer sampler]

Comment: FYI, it's crucial to open that link in an **incognito** window. I've edited your answer.

Comment: @kynan: Why? I haven't found that to be true.

Comment: Interestingly in your example it is indeed not true and I'm not quite sure why. Note that if you did reopen your shared album in an incognito window, the image URL will be an "unauthenticated" 140 character hash instead of a 755 character "secret" hash as in your case, see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/137631/23501). These are meant to expire afaiu, I assume for privacy reasons, but maybe that's not the case if the image is part of a shared album?

Comment: Almost 5 years later and the image url is still alive and kicking. That's cool

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Blogger to get a proper URL for an image from Google Photos, and then to display it in your website the way you'd display any other image.

Answer (score 1):

Google contents supports parameters to define output image size. You can attach `=w640-h480` after image url to define specific size, in this example width to 640 pixels and height to 480 pixels. If you want to optimize size of image is faster and easier way to use this tool: https://www.publicalbum.org/blog/embedding-google-photos-image

Answer (score -2):

Chrom : One way I just found out by chance, in the archive keep the photo small (ie do not zoom it out by clicking on it) and right-click on it. Select the last option of Inspect. When you select Inspect, a panel opens on the right hand side and the  embed path of the image is highlighted in blue. Go to that blue part and right click  --> copy --> copy element. Paste this wherever you want.

The only thing is there are no  default options for the size as there were in PicasawebAlbums. So resizing can be a problem as the image becomes blurred.