# Google Sheets URL length limit?

Tags: google-sheets, url

**Is there a length limit for a URL (especially for an embedded image) in Google Sheets?**

I'm trying to create a cell with an image by a specific URL, in the following way:

```
=IMAGE(URL)
```

It works at the creation moment, but a short time afterwards it's not showing the picture anymore. I checked a few times a day later, and the image was missing, although the URL is valid.

Tried to both give `IMAGE` a direct URL (with quote marks), and also pointing it to a cell that contains a URL.

`https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-mK3Eid7Vg8ytUbbe3W7x-0ZrFE_nXPMrYpIG8ZfhkCop1lSVv8PrY00YGrt_sqLOEaHnqdb0zRft-2YviQ1R_1HPkVxM9U8Ryb8pNFZzy-GHYHEBFWjUByFf-8ifYye1OqvL_Bo287cF6TPLJZx8l9zK6hB6TKVjDQdTqBv9g_vMoyH1oV_OzVPsXfGkqYSgENyviTXjvEeLZjv1HEIx0dFEMVxBULhdY6VaQgNcwHXiMiUf552Z-wA3AXLSA7vZ8d3oZgwb6cEB0d4JwwSGugR-wO0_QtMo6CZGuwe-gddNBiPEhCjs93UqzhAxAfYfC2NHEsgcQN7tor84CNRnbSUoxGh3Ee3YXMvzXlXRL9yWEdX2q7OgG7wzMz0sTEZt81BxlzVeY2g2tvHAB5Hp_HpzTEbGN0dBp3tMWuE-bkf3jbCHOGag70H8ti-8p82ZVjF6Evn9Wk8OZEhAcW9u_04DpTFrIQj_zUw3cl6E4BMkM3iVvFzoOdUNZC60O1ID453BEi9EWGP7_DneZ7-mjl2MFqinXM0GvhEMq4_NYljU-uNM704fOrD49O0GaGJatY7RfkRwocVc4ZTjcq_DF2ozhSeV8q5kbH1y7S_=w728-h947-no`

[Here's an example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iLvTvJGjbEJchICI1zg-dyZTmQF3cChvPaIBH_jngrE/edit?usp=sharing) - all worked on creation.

The URLs that I tested with, were 663 chars long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/...` are temporary URLs. See [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/98573/88163) to [How to get the direct link to an image in my Google Photos?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92777/88163)

Comment: Thanks! since that was the problem, which I haven't identified correctly - I have marked it as a duplicate